# Fetch the latest post with attachment image

Tags: images

What I want to do seems to be simple but I can't get around it. I'd like to get the latest post that has an image attachment. A little help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Lita

Comment: What I had so far was getting the latest attachment post but thank you bcorkins solution works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tricky one. If you wanted to get the latest image attachment and display the post associated with it, you could use:

```
$attachments = get_posts('post_type=attachment');
$first_attachment_post = get_post($attachments[0]->post_parent);
```

To get the latest post, but only if it has an attachment, I think the only way to do it would be with two nested queries. For example:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

        $attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => get_the_ID(), 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image') );

        if ( $attachments ) {
            // Post output here will only be display if attachments are found
            echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
        }
endwhile;
```